# Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) for $2 \theta^2 x^{-3}$

Tags: self-study, estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, estimators

I'm having a bit of trouble solving this.

$$
f(x_i; \theta) = 2 \theta^2 x_i^{-3}, 0 \le \theta \le x_i \lt \infty
$$

I start by finding $f(\textbf{x}; \theta)$:

$$
f(\textbf{x}; \theta) = \prod{f(x_i; \theta)} = (2 \theta^2 x_i^{-3})^n = L(\theta; \textbf{x})
$$

Now calculate log-likelihood:

$$
ln(L) = n \ln(2) + 2 n \ln(\theta) - 3 \sum_i \ln(x_i)
$$

Differentiate wrt $\theta$ and set to 0:

$$
\frac{2 n}{\theta} = 0
$$

So MLE of $\theta$ is $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have not taken account of the bound on the parameter that was specified in your original sampling density.  Taking account of this bound, gives the log-likelihood function:

$$\ell_\mathbf{x}(\theta) = n \ln 2 + 2n \ln \theta - 3\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \min \{ x_1,...,x_n  \}.$$

Differentiating gives the score function:

$$s_\mathbf{x}(\theta) \equiv \frac{d\ell_\mathbf{x}}{d\theta}(\theta) = \frac{2n}{\theta} \quad \quad \quad \text{for all } 0 < \theta < \min \{ x_1,...,x_n  \}.$$

So, you have a likelihood that is monotonically increasing over the range $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \min \{ x_1,...,x_n  \}$.  What does that tell you about the MLE?  (Hint: It is not infinity.)

Comment: Thanks. Then to find MLE, there is no point of $\frac{d\ell_\mathbf{x}}{d\theta}(\theta)  = 0$, that is differentiating and setting to 0 does not give us the max likelihood. What I can say is that $l_{\textbf{x}}(\theta)$ is maximised when $2 n \ln(\theta)$ is maximised which is when $\theta = min(x_1,...,x_n)$

Comment: Yes - you have a monotonically increasing function over a compact interval, so the maximising value occurs at the boundary point - there are no critical points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your likelihood is incorrect. All of the individual data points are different, so you shouldn't forget their subscripts. In the second line, each place you write $x$ should be replaced with $x_i$.

Comment: fixed but it wouldn't make a difference when you differentiate wrt $\theta$

Comment: Yes, and @Ben has done a nice job explaining the other mistake. You might also consider plotting the log likelihood against theta after specifying some specific sample maximum.